# Variance inequality to show deviation from midpoint

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

How to show this inequality:

> If $\mathbb P (X \in [a,b]) = 1$, then $\operatorname{Var}(X) \leqslant \frac{(a-b)^2}{4}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assume $b>a$, otherwise $X$ is constant hence its variance is $0$.

Write $Y:=\frac{X-a}{b-a}$; then $P(Y\in [0,1])=1$, so we are reduced to prove that $\operatorname{Var}(Y)\leqslant \frac 14$. We have $$0\leqslant E(X^2)-E(X)^2\leqslant E(X)-E(X)^2=E(X)(1-E(X)).$$
The last task consists in checking that $t(1-t)\leqslant 1/4$ for any $t\in [0,1]$.